# Why most of Flutterfire's pages are ARCHIVED?

Tags: flutter, firebase

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview

It's been a while since I looked at flutterfire's documentation, but I found the following note on almost every page.

> Notice
>
> This page is archived and might not reflect the latest version of the
> FlutterFire plugins. You can find the latest information on
> firebase.google.com:

What is the situation with this?

Will https://firebase.flutter.dev not be updated anymore?

Answer (score 1):

The link from FlutterFire mentioned that it's not the official document. It is maintained by googlers.
https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
How much less reliable is this compared to "supported products"?
Does that mean that no one knows because it's a future story?

Comment: But what does "archived" mean? Is the project not maintained anymore?

Comment: @StanislavModrák When a project is archived on GitHub, it means that the repository is still available for viewing and forking, but it is no longer actively maintained or updated by the original author or maintainers. This usually means that the project has been completed or is no longer considered useful, but the repository is kept available for historical or reference purposes.